# Getting list of distinct values from shapefile field using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sql, fields-attributes, list

I have a shapefile whose features I can filter by specifying a where clause in the query dialogue. F.x. I have a field named `"city_name"` and by stating `"city_name" = 'London'` in the where clause only London is displayed. What I would like to do now is to fetch all values in `"city_name"` from the attribute table.

Something like that:

```sql
select distinct city_name
from [attribute table]
```

I found several tools in QGIS apparently deal with SQL and I also had a quick look at the different Plugins. But I fail at connecting to a database or the table name ... what database or which table in that case?

In the end, I want to export the result list and use it for further processing.

I am using QGIS 1.8.

Comment: Can you please show a visual example of what you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Update answer (QGIS Version >= 2.14)**

[Since QGIS 2.14](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog214/index.html#feature-virtual-layers), you can use run SQL statements on any loaded vector layer using [Virtual layers](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers.html?highlight=virtual%20layers).

1. Having the layer loaded in QGIS, go to **Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer**;
2. In the Create virtual layer dialog, enter your SQL statement in the Query field. Something like:

   ```sql
   SELECT DISTINCT city_name
   FROM layer_name
   ```
3. For the geometry set *No Geometry*
4. Click Ok and a table will load in QGIS with the desired unique values.

Note: this table will be updated if new values are added to the city_name column.

**Legacy answer (QGIS Version < 2.14)**

You have a few choices to do what you ask.

1. Import your shapefile in a Spatialite or Postgis database, and then you can query your table using complete SQL statements;
2. Use the Dissolve tool (Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve), to dissolve your shapefiles using the field "city_name". Although is a strange method, the `.dbf` file of the resulting shapefile will provide the list you need;
3. Take a look at [group stats plugin (1.6)](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/), you can use `"city_name"` as a classification field, and press calculate. It will calculate some stats about each city, you can then copy the result and extract the city list.

---

I have just noticed that in the **Vector > Analysis Tools**, there is a **List unique Values** tool that is precisely what one needs for this task. So easy... no workarounds and no need for Plugins.

Answer (score 16):

QGIS now has a tool that will list unique values in one or more fields in a layer. "This algorithm generates a report with information about the unique values found in a given attribute (or attributes) of a vector layer."

Can be found in main menu Vector> Analysis Tools> List Unique Values. Generates a table with unique values.

Answer (score 8):

Use the QGIS DB Manager and access your shapefile via 'virtual layers'

You can then use the SQL window and write your query:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use a virtual layer:

```
select "district", "thedatefield"
from yourtable
group by "district", "thedatefield"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered an alternate way to solve my question by using the *Delete Duplicates by Attribute* tool.  Simply select both the inspection date and district fields in the *Field to match duplicates by* section.  Voila!  The output exactly matches the table generated by BERA's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try including something like:

```
where city_name is NOT NULL or not equal to NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

2023 you can do this by 3 different ways

Step by step walk through each method click here

https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/1180/how-to-find-unique-value-part-5-qgis

I prefer SQL method,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Use query builder in QGIS, go to city name field in fields in query builder.
Go to values, add all. Delete any nulls.

Build a script similar to city name = "london" and city name = "paris" until you have the complete list of names and run the script. Now all city names are selected. You can export selected as a shape file and import into a postgresql database.

To use a postgresql backend to QGIS install a postgresql stack with geoserver, postgresql, and a postgis enabled databse in postgresql. You will need to connect QGIS to the server. Play around a bit and you will figure it out.