# QGIS: how to label a continent map with distinct values from shapefile?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table

I have a continent shapefile containing the names of its different countries. Unfortunately, many of these countries have more than one entry (i.e. more than one row in the attribute table).

Therefore, when I am trying to add labels of the country names to the map, some of country names are printed out more than one time.

I read [Getting list of distinct values from shapefile field using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49186/how-to-get-a-list-of-distinct-values-from-a-shapefile-field-using-qgis), but was not able to apply it to my specific problem.

What can I do about this?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to remove the duplicate countries in your shapefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a dissolve on the shape file so that the shape file only contains a single entry based on country you can them label as required

Comment: No worries.  Glad it helped