# QGIS List Unique Values tool only exports to .html format

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, unique-value

Using QGIS 2.16.2 I would like to export the unique values in a shapefile string attribute field to a new database table (which would contain a single field listing the unique values).  The Vector > Analysis Tools > List Unique Values tool correctly selects the unique values, but the only output option is an .html file.  Is there some way to output to a .dbf, or .csv format?

The shapefile is a line format, so the Dissolve tool does not work (it requires a polygon input), as described in [Getting list of distinct values from shapefile field using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49186/getting-list-of-distinct-values-from-shapefile-field-using-qgis)

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If so, please mark it as accepted to let others know this post is officially solved (see http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 6):

Go to `DB Manager -> Virtual Layers -> QGIS layers`, click on `SQL Window` button (or press F2), and write the next SQL expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT your_field FROM your_layer ORDER BY your_field;
```

Once you get the result table, click on `Load as new layer`, uncheck `Geometry column`, and click on `Load now!`.

[image]

Now you have a table layer in QGIS, which you can export with `right click -> Save As...` to a CSV file, for example.

Comment: @ German Carrillo Thank you.  Following your advice, I use this SQL expression: SELECT DISTINCT junk FROM 2015_08_01 ORDER BY junk;  This error results:  Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS SELECT DISTINCT junk FROM 2015_08_01 ORDER BY junk;: 1 - unrecognized token: "2015_08_01"     FYI, 2015_08_01 is the shapefile name and junk is the string attribute field.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your table name seems to be special (only numbers and underscores), so you need to use quotation marks. Try with "2015_08_01" in the SQL sentence.

Comment: Note that there is also a button called "Add VIrtual Layer" in QGIS. You could use it to avoid opening the DB Manager.

Answer (score 1):

2023 you can do this by 3 different ways

Step by step walk through each method click here

https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/1180/how-to-find-unique-value-part-5-qgis

I prefer SQL method,

[image]

[image]

[image]