# QGIS - Let atlas iterate through distinct values of virtual field

Tags: qgis, atlas, virtual-layer, virtual-field

I have a CSV-Layer with multiple columns (e.g. ID, owner_name) and well-known text data to contain information about polygons.
One ID can be owned by to owners which would cause the feature to appear twice in the attribute table. I further created a virtual field which concentrates all owners into it.

The code of the virtual field looks like this

```
concatenate("owner_name" ,group_by:= "ID",concatenator:=', ',order_by:= "owner_name")
```

This results in a attribute table as follows

| ID | owner_name | all_owners [virtual field] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Simon | Simon |
| 2 | Erica | Erica, Peter |
| 2 | Peter | Erica, Peter |
| 3 | Simon | Simon |

Now I want to the atlas to iterate through all unique values in the all_owners column. In this case:

1. Simon
2. Erica, Peter

**Important**: I do not want to create new (static) layers and use the dissolve function as the data in the "CSV"-Layer might get changed later on and everything shall get updated.

**Note**: The answer to this similar question ([look here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303829/using-only-distinct-values-to-iterate-as-atlas-features-in-qgis)) does not work, as Virtual Layers cannot get access to virtual fields as far as I tried.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, is create a virtual layer that selects the distinct values of the "all_owners" column and join the geom's to that table. You could then build the atlas on that derivative virtual layer.

This is really doing in qgis with virtual layers what I would do permanently in postgres but I think would work.

I don't work a ton with virtual layers but based on my understanding, they would update automatically when the source data is updated.

This is not pulling from a csv with a virtual column but you should be able to import your csv layer and access your virtual column by name.

The query i just tested was:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I couldn't make that work: How Do select distinct values from a virtual field? 
The list of distinct values in the virtual layer would be enough as I can show the features of the original layer using a rule-based style pointing to the "atlas_pagename"

Comment: start by just `select * from my_csv_layer`  and check that the virtual layer was pulled through and then just switch to selecting `distinct column_name`

Comment: This does not work. I get a promt: "Query preparation error on PRAGMA table_info(_tview): no such column: all_owners"

I guess this happens because the virtual layer accesses the original CSV-file (which is not containing the virtual field) and not the imported CSV-layer (which contains the virtual field)

Comment: are you "adding" the csv _file_ or "importing" the _layer_

Comment: I am "importing" the layer. It also shows me the field name as a hint/autocomplete when beginning to type. However the above error is shown as soon as I want to add the layer. With static fields it works just fine. 
Is there maybe another work around to achieve the outcome described in the question?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that creates your virtual field? I'd recommend taking this off s/o and joining then emailing qgis-user@lists.osgeo.org. you can join here https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-user

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I edited the question as you suggested.

Comment: I was not able to solve this issue yet. Also the signhup to the mailinglist, was somehow not succesful (I tried over the course of the last weeks, but did not receive any info back). Do you have any advice for me?